# React Data Grid rows disappearing on dynamically providing height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-data-grid, react-grid-layout

I am trying to make `RDG Table` which can be expanded(for expansion i have used `ReactGridLayout`) in height & Width. I am using `react-sizeme` for dynamically providing `height` & `Width` to my component(in my case `Example` component). Now, Table is getting expanded in height & Width correctly when scrollbar in table is at top.
Below image shows Table with scrollbar at top:
[image: ScrollBar at top]
If i expand table, everything will work correctly as in below image:
[image]

As soon as we bring Scrollbar somewhat in between and then expand table's height, rows are getting disappeared. These rows become visible as soon as i scroll by just a small amount in table.
For e.g. In below image, Scrollbar is in not in beginning(row6 is visible).
[image: Scroll bar is not at beginning]

Now if i expand table, some rows are getting disappeared as shown in below image:
[image: Rows getting disappeared]

I am unable to understand why rows are getting disappeared on expansion when scrollbar is not in beginning.

CodeSandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/rdg-optimising-scrolling-n6xpj

Edit: Table contains 199 rows currently.

Answer (score 2):

When scrollbar is in between and component is resized(by increasing height), RDG will not know that it has to render new rows to fill empty rows created by increasing height. That's why as soon as, i scroll manually by just a small amount, RDG will know that it has to render new rows and everything will work fine.

So, now problem was reduced to making RDG understand that it has to render new rows.

For this, i kept `key: Math.random()` in state and passed this key to RDG as prop.
On resizing, i am checking if new height is not equal to previous height and if so, update `key` in state which will re-render entire RDG.

I know this is not efficient solution but it won't matter since i will have max 200 rows.

Working Code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/rdg-optimising-scrolling-pgso9

Edit(24-08-2019):
Above mentioned code will bring `scroll position` to always at top because we are creating entirely new table everytime there is change in height. So, i tried keeping `scroll position` at the same place and arrived at more optimised code.

First of all, i removed `key` from `state` because it is no longer required.
Then, in `scroll callback function`, i saved `scrollTop` position in `state`.

Now once there is any change in height, 2 things are required to be done:

```
1. Scroll to `zeroth` row.
2. Scroll to `scrollTop`.
Point 1 is required so that RDG can be made aware that their was change in height. 
This way it will render additional rows to fill entire table.
```

Code is present here: https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-optimising-scrolling-7lvdv

Comment: This solves the main problem, but you lose the scroll position.  Have you been able to work around that?

Comment: @JørgenTvedt In my case, `losing scroll position` was not an issue. But, it is good question which i haven't explored. Will share some solution if i find something useful.

Comment: @JørgenTvedt I have solved `losing scroll position` problem and edited my answer with explanation and code.

Answer (score 1):

I think no need to change the state for just to make DOM refresh.
you can do it by generating a new key to wrapper div of RDG.

```
<div key={Math.random()}>
  <ReactDataGrid
    columns={this.state.columns}
    rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
    rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
    minHeight={height}
    onScroll={this.onScroll}
  />
</div>
```

Try this.

Comment: This would rerender entire RDG whenever there is any change in any prop whereas i want to rerender only when there is change in height of component.